# The inplace method (wihout using extra space) of merging two sorted Linked List is not working in C++

Tags: merge, linked-list

[Code Written by me for merging two sorted Linked List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJPnt.png)
`I am comparing two element and then connecting them as per requirement.. but idk why it is not working? it is failing at some test cases like list1: 1 2 4 list2: 1 3 4 etc. Can anybody help me with this?`

Comment: No images of code please. Type the text and format it.